# Determining which part of a JSON Schema a given word belongs to with monaco

Tags: json, jsonschema, monaco-editor

I'm using the monaco editor for validating JSON in accordance with a custom schema, such as is described in [this Playground example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults).

Next, I'd like to customize a hover event whose behavior depends on which part of the schema is being hovered over. I can easily add a hover event that knows what word I'm hovering over, by just adding some code like this:

```
monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider('json', {
  provideHover: function(model, position) {
    // get the word that the cursor is currently hovering over
    var word = model.getWordAtPosition(position);
    var wordRange = new monaco.Range(position.lineNumber, word.startColumn, position.lineNumber, word.endColumn);

    return {
      contents: [{ value: 'This word is: ' + word.word }],
      range: wordRange
    };
  }
});
```

But what I also need to know is the schema path-- something like this, but with a properly functioning `getSchemaPart()`:

```
function getSchemaPart(model, position) {
  return ['http://myserver/bar-schema.json#', 'p1'].join('/');  // How do I do this properly?
}

monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider('json', {
  provideHover: function(model, position) {
    // get the word that the cursor is currently hovering over
    var word = model.getWordAtPosition(position);
    var wordRange = new monaco.Range(position.lineNumber, word.startColumn, position.lineNumber, word.endColumn);

    var schemaPart = getSchemaPart(model, position);

    return {
      contents: [{ value: 'This word is: ' + word.word + ' and its schema part is ' + schemaPart }],
      range: wordRange
    };
  }
});
```

Clearly, Monaco already knows this information since it's needed for validation. Is there any way to fetch it in my hover event?

Alternatively, is there a clean way to use some other library and feed it the entire JSON value, and then figure out what schema part applies to the particular position that is being hovered over? This latter approach seems feasible in theory but challenging when considering that there may be whitespace in the input which the parser ignores, and therefore it requires mapping positions to tokens to schema parts.